# ReactJS: Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: reactjs, constructor, setstate

I am trying to refactor the following code from my render view:

```
<Button href="#" active={!this.state.singleJourney} onClick={this.handleButtonChange.bind(this,false)} >Retour</Button>
```

to a version where the bind is within the constructor. The reason for that is that bind in the render view will give me performance issues, especially on low end mobile phones.

I have created the following code, but I am constantly getting the following errors (lots of them). It looks like the app gets in a loop:

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

Below is the code I use:

```
var React = require('react');
var ButtonGroup = require('react-bootstrap/lib/ButtonGroup');
var Button = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Button');
var Form = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Form');
var FormGroup = require('react-bootstrap/lib/FormGroup');
var Well = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Well');

export default class Search extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            singleJourney: false
        };

        this.handleButtonChange = this.handleButtonChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleButtonChange(value) {
        this.setState({
            singleJourney: value
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Form>

                <Well style={wellStyle}>

                    <FormGroup className="text-center">

                        <ButtonGroup>
                            <Button href="#" active={!this.state.singleJourney} onClick={this.handleButtonChange(false)} >Retour</Button>
                            <Button href="#" active={this.state.singleJourney} onClick={this.handleButtonChange(true)} >Single Journey</Button>
                        </ButtonGroup>
                    </FormGroup>

                </Well>

            </Form>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Search;
```

Comment: I have this same issue but now related to onClick(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57079814/react-cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transition-such-as-within-render

Comment: This same issue but without onClick(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57079814/react-cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transition-such-as-within-render

Answer (score 383, accepted):

Looks like you're accidentally calling the `handleButtonChange` method in your render method, you probably want to do `onClick={() => this.handleButtonChange(false)}` instead.

If you don't want to create a lambda in the onClick handler, I think you'll need to have two bound methods, one for each parameter.

In the `constructor`:

```
this.handleButtonChangeRetour = this.handleButtonChange.bind(this, true);
this.handleButtonChangeSingle = this.handleButtonChange.bind(this, false);
```

And in the `render` method:

```
<Button href="#" active={!this.state.singleJourney} onClick={this.handleButtonChangeSingle} >Retour</Button>
<Button href="#" active={this.state.singleJourney} onClick={this.handleButtonChangeRetour}>Single Journey</Button>
```

Comment: I have tried that solution, and it works. But I don't see this solution online anywere as preferred solution. What I want to accomplish is that my bind is outside the render view. In this solution, this.handleButtonChange = this.handleButtonChange.bind(this); in the constructor is not needed anymore, does that mean that my binding is again in my render view?

Comment: Maybe what happens is when i set the active state, it will trigger onClick, resulting in a loop. is there any way to set active state without triggering onClick?

Comment: Why a lambda is the solution? Which concept is behind this? I can not see it.

Comment: The main difference is between  onClick={this.handleButtonChange(false)} and onClick={() => this.handleButtonChange(false)} - the first one is wrong in that it just invokes the handleButtonChange method immediately and assigns its return value (undefined) to the onClick handle - therefore nothing happens. The second one actually assigns a method to onClick - one that invokes handleButtonChange.

Comment: I have a senior supervisor on React helping me from time to time. He says I should avoid anonymous functions because performance issues. He says an anonymous function allocates memory that doesn't get destroyed or something like that. I would like to know the opinion of you about this, thanks.

Comment: There are cases where the anonymous function would hurt performance, the most common one being when the component you pass the anonymous function to as a prop (Button in the example) defines shouldComponentUpdate that compares props using === (e.g. PureComponent). Passing an anonymous function prevents this optimization from working, since a new instance of the function is created on every render, therefore the === in shouldComponentUpdate always returns false and the child component has to re-render. In such cases, it's better to use a named method like in the second half of my answer.

Comment: You can read more about this issue in [this article](https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f).

Comment: with  onFocus={() => this.handleButtonChange(false)}  is not working, but onFocus={ this.handleButtonChange(false)}  works but  give me error because in that function i use .setState and, it's forbiden in render... any advise?

Comment: @VladimirRovensky thanks for your clear explanation. A question: when you said that If you don't want to create a lambda... create 2 funcs, I wonder if the lamda is needed only when we want to pass an argument to an event handler. In other words: do I need a lamda just when Im trying to script a function to handle multiple options (instead than one function per each option)?

Answer (score 19):

I am giving a generic example for better understanding, In the following code

```html
render(){
    return(
      <div>

        <h3>Simple Counter</h3>
        <Counter
          value={this.props.counter}
          onIncrement={this.props.increment()} <------ calling the function
          onDecrement={this.props.decrement()} <-----------
          onIncrementAsync={this.props.incrementAsync()} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

When supplying props I am calling the function directly, this wold have a infinite loop execution and would give you that error, Remove the function call everything works normally.

```html
render(){
    return(
      <div>

        <h3>Simple Counter</h3>
        <Counter
          value={this.props.counter}
          onIncrement={this.props.increment} <------ function call removed
          onDecrement={this.props.decrement} <-----------
          onIncrementAsync={this.props.incrementAsync} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: No wonder at that time, I got infinite loop exception. silly me. After that, I'm using `bind` button on `constructor` and arrow function `()=>`

Answer (score 15):

That usually happens when you call

**`onClick={this.handleButton`**()**`}`** - notice the **()** instead of:

**`onClick={this.handleButton`}** - notice here we are not calling the function when we initialize it

Answer (score 9):

**THE PROBLEM** is here: `onClick={this.handleButtonChange(false)}`

When you pass `this.handleButtonChange(false)` to onClick, you are actually calling the function with `value = false` and setting onClick to the function's return value, which is undefined. Also, calling `this.handleButtonChange(false)` then calls  `this.setState()` which triggers a re-render, resulting in an infinite render loop.

**THE SOLUTION** is to pass the function in a lambda: `onClick={() => this.handleButtonChange(false)}`. Here you are setting onClick to equal a function that will call handleButtonChange(false) when the button is clicked.

The below example may help:

```
function handleButtonChange(value){
  console.log("State updated!")
}

console.log(handleButtonChange(false))
//output: State updated!
//output: undefined

console.log(() => handleButtonChange(false))
//output: ()=>{handleButtonChange(false);}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to add arguments to a handler in `recompose`, make sure that you're defining your arguments correctly in the handler. It is essentially a curried function, so you want to be sure to require the correct number of arguments. [This page has a good example of using arguments with handlers.](https://recompose.docsforhumans.com/withhandlers.html)

Example (from the link):

```
withHandlers({
  handleClick: props => (value1, value2) => event => {
    console.log(event)
    alert(value1 + ' was clicked!')
    props.doSomething(value2)
  },
})
```

for your child HOC and in the parent

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    handleClick: PropTypes.func, 
  }
  render () {
    const {handleClick} = this.props
    return (
      <div onClick={handleClick(value1, value2)} />
    )
  }
}
```

this avoids writing an anonymous function out of your handler to patch fix the problem with not supplying enough parameter names on your handler.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is certainly the this binding while rending the button with onClick handler. The solution is to use arrow function while calling action handler while rendering. Like this: 
    `onClick={ () => this.handleButtonChange(false) }`

Comment: Gooood idea! :)

Answer (score 2):

From react docs [Passing arguments to event handlers](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers)

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>
<button onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this, id)}>Delete Row</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This same warning will be emitted on any state changes done in a `render()` call.

An example of a tricky to find case:
When rendering a multi-select GUI component based on state data, if state has nothing to display, a call to `resetOptions()` is considered state change for that component.

The obvious fix is to do `resetOptions()` in `componentDidUpdate()` instead of `render()`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I was calling

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

in my constructor when **handleClick didn't exist**

(I had erased it and had accidentally left the "this" binding statement in my constructor).

Solution = remove the "this" binding statement.

Answer (score 1):

The onClick function must pass through a function that returns the handleButtonChange() method. Otherwise it will run automatically, ending up with the error/warning. Use the below to solve the issue.

```html
onClick={() => this.handleButtonChange(false)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I use to open Popover for components is [reactstrap (React Bootstrap 4 components)](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/popovers/).

```
    class Settings extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
              popoversOpen: [] // array open popovers
            }
        }

        // toggle my popovers
        togglePopoverHelp = (selected) => (e) => {
            const index = this.state.popoversOpen.indexOf(selected);
            if (index < 0) {
              this.state.popoversOpen.push(selected);
            } else {
              this.state.popoversOpen.splice(index, 1);
            }
            this.setState({ popoversOpen: [...this.state.popoversOpen] });
        }

        render() {
            <div id="settings">
                <button id="PopoverTimer" onClick={this.togglePopoverHelp(1)} className="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button">?</button>
                <Popover placement="left" isOpen={this.state.popoversOpen.includes(1)} target="PopoverTimer" toggle={this.togglePopoverHelp(1)}>
                  <PopoverHeader>Header popover</PopoverHeader>
                  <PopoverBody>Description popover</PopoverBody>
                </Popover>

                <button id="popoverRefresh" onClick={this.togglePopoverHelp(2)} className="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button">?</button>
                <Popover placement="left" isOpen={this.state.popoversOpen.includes(2)} target="popoverRefresh" toggle={this.togglePopoverHelp(2)}>
                  <PopoverHeader>Header popover 2</PopoverHeader>
                  <PopoverBody>Description popover2</PopoverBody>
                </Popover>
            </div>
        }
    }
```