# Difference of .bind() to arrow function () => usage in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding, arrow-functions

Suppose that I have a function `generateList()` that updates the state and mapping it to an onClick to a `<li>.`

```
<li className="some-classname"}  
    onClick={this.generateList('product')}> Product </li>
```

There are times that I encounter errors like:

`Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props...`

And such. I mined the internet for answers for this, and came upon such [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37387846/3458391) like:

```
<li className="some-classname"}  
    onClick={this.generateList.bind(this, 'product')}> Product </li>
```

But I saw one answer too (in Github, but can't seem to find it) that

```
<li className="some-classname"}  
    onClick={() => this.generateList('product')}> Product </li>
```

What's the major difference? Which is more appropriate and efficient? And what's the reason that we should use such `.bind` and `() =>` when mapping a function to an `onClick` or as a property of a React component (which I mostly use it)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding vs arrow-function (JavaScript or react onClick)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375440/binding-vs-arrow-function-javascript-or-react-onclick)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you try:

```
<li className="some-classname"}  
    onClick={this.generateList('product')}> Product </li>
```

That function will be **executed** on every render - which can produce an additional render, which is what throws the error. What we want is to **define** a function that will be called later when `onClick` is fired.

The second one is defining a method and `.bind` is binding the context of the React class `this` to the method. Note that the `bind` function returns a copy of a function - So this doesn't call the function, just defines it for the `onClick` handler to use.

The last one:

```
<li className="some-classname"}  
    onClick={() => this.generateList('product')}> Product </li>
```

This defines an anonymous function but, similar to the second implementation, does not call it. Only when `onClick` is fired is it called. However in some cases using an anonymous function can cause performance issues. That anonymous function will be defined on every render - and if you have a component that is re-rendering very often it can hurt the performance of your application. If you are sure that the component will not be rendered often, an anonymous function should be fine for convenience.

Additionally when using bind you can declare it in the component class constructor like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // your state
    };
    this.generateList = this.generateList.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: Hey, I had a mistake, sorry. It's supposed to be `() => this.generateList('product')}`.

Comment: Yep, so as far as I am concerned with performance, I must always opt to `bind` the function at the constructor then I am free to use it within the `render`?

Comment: @erik-sn, when using bind, the function will be defined on every render like an anonymous function?