# this is null in one function, not in another of the same class

Tags: reactjs

In my React/JS application. this is part of the Component class I have:

```
<p>
            <input
              onChange={ this.handleEmailChange } value={ this.props.email } type='email'
              className={ this.state.error ? 'form-control loginCredentialError shakeElement' : 'form-control' }
              name='email'
              placeholder='Email' required='True'
            />
            <input
              onChange={ this.handlePasswordChange } value={ this.props.password } type='password'
              className={ this.state.error ? 'form-control loginCredentialError shakeElement' : 'form-control' } name='password'
              placeholder='Password' required='True'
            />
          </p>
          <p>
            <Button
              onClick={ (event) => this.handleLoginClick(event) }
              className='btn btn-round-lg btn-round btn-primary btn-block center-block'
            >Sign In</Button>
          </p>
```

As you can see I have `handleEmailChange`, `handlePasswordChange`, and `handleLoginClick`. **Those three functions are of the same `Component` class as the `render` function**

In this function, the `this` is evaluated as `null`, which makes `this.setState` fail.

```
handleEmailChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value);
    this.setState({ email: value });
  }
```

however, in this function the `this` is fine and has a value. `setState` works well. Can anyone please let me know why the difference in these seemingly similar functions?

```
handleLoginClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const payload = {
      'email': this.state.email,
      'password': this.state.password,
    };

    this.setState({ communicating: true, error: false, errorServer: false });
...
...
...
```

Comment: IT's because of arrow function that returns handleLoginClick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This difference here is in binding. If you look at how you set the onChange of Button and Input, in one you use an arrow function for `handleLoginClick` and the other you use `{this.handleEmailChange}`.

The arrow function automatically binds `this` to the function. There are two ways to fix this. Either:

```
onChange = {this.handleEmailChange.bind(this)}
```

or

```
onChange = {(event) => handleEmailChange(event)}
```

This will create a binding between the function and the `this` that you are setting the state of.

Check out : [Difference of .bind() to arrow function () => usage in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715182/difference-of-bind-to-arrow-function-usage-in-react) for more info on binding to context using arrow functions or .bind()

Comment: ah! yes... I forgot about biding. Thanks !

Comment: It gets me every time!

Comment: binding. that is. not biding.