# JavaScript binding - arrow functions and bind

Tags: javascript, binding

I have this bit of code:

```
const data = {
  x: "Target"
}

let bar = () => {
  console.log(this.x)
}

let final = bar.bind(data); 
final();
```

This code returns undefined. Here is the same code, but with non-arrow functions:

```
const data = {
  x: "Target"
}

let bar = function(){
  console.log(this.x)
}

let final = bar.bind(data); 
final();
```

This code works. I want to understand why the arrow function kept the binding from working. I know that they handle *this* differently. I know that they keep the original context in which they were called, which in this case does not include x. But does it also prevent bind() from working?

Comment: **See** [**Binding vs Arrow-function** (in JavaScript, or for react onClick)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50375440/8740349)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But does it also prevent bind() from working?

Partially, because `bind` returns a new function that calls the original function with a specific `this` — but arrow functions don't use the `this` they're called with, they completely ignore it. Instead, they *close over* the `this` where they're defined.

`bind` on an arrow function can't change the arrow's concept of `this`. All it can do is its secondary feature, pre-supplying arguments:

```js
"use strict";
function run() {
  const f = (a, b, c) => {
    console.log("this", this);
    console.log("a", a);
    console.log("b", b);
    console.log("c", c);
  };

  const fbound = f.bind({}, 1, 2, 3);
  f();
  fbound();
}
run();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;£
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrow function takes precedence over bind. Whenever there are two or more different ways of setting this context, they are resolved in the following order:
-arrow functions
-new keyword
-bind
-call or apply