# React Js best practice - onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I worked with 3 different scenarios to call a function using onClick event, but I was never sure about which one I should stick with, I will demonstrate my question with a basic example but let's imagine our tFunction is more complicated than updating a state.

```
const [state, setState] = useState("");
```

1st scenario  :

```
const tFunction = (e) => {
const tValue = e.target.getAttribute("name");
setState(tValue)};

<button name={"some data"} onClick={tFunction}>Press me</button>
```

2nd scenario  :

```
  const tFunction = (value) => {setState(value)};

  <button onClick={() => tFunction("some data")}> Press me </button>
```

3rd scenario  :

```
  <button onClick={() => setState("some data")}> Press me </button>
```

My question is : what is the best scenario that I should always follow?

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-cache-6th3m?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: What is `value` in your 2nd and 3rd scenarios? it is not defined

Comment: Related for non-hooks: [Binding vs Arrow-function (in JavaScript, or for react onClick)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375440/binding-vs-arrow-function-in-javascript-or-for-react-onclick). That said, the code snippets here aren't clearly similar as Ba2sik mentioned, nor are they valid JS. Please share runnable, working snippets.

Comment: I replace value with just a text something to update the state with.
I provided a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using an arrow function in render creates a new function each time the
> component renders, which may break optimizations based on strict
> identity comparison.

(From React documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Thus, you should go 1st scenario.

Answer (score -1):

The first scenario makes you code run faster and can be reusable for other buttons, so I suggest the first scenario