# Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition with redux/immutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting the error

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

I found the cause to be

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    notifications: state.get("notifications").get("notifications").toJS()
  }
}
```

If I do not return notifications there it works. But why is that?

```
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import {removeNotification, deactivateNotification} from "./actions"
import Notifications from "./Notifications.jsx"

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    notifications: state.get("notifications").get("notifications").toJS()
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    closeNotification: (notification) => {
      dispatch(deactivateNotification(notification.id))
      setTimeout(() => dispatch(removeNotification(notification.id)), 2000)
    }
  }
}

const NotificationsBotBot = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Notifications)
export default NotificationsBotBot

import React from "react"

class Notifications extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    )
  }
}

export default Notifications
```

**UPDATE**

On further debugging I found that, the above may not be the root cause after all, I can have the notifications stay but I need to remove `dispatch(push("/domains"))` my redirect.

This is how I login:

```
export function doLogin (username, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(loginRequest())
    console.log("Simulated login with", username, password)
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(loginSuccess(`PLACEHOLDER_TOKEN${Date.now()}`))
      dispatch(addNotification({
        children: "Successfully logged in",
        type: "accept",
        timeout: 2000,
        action: "Ok"
      }))
      dispatch(push("/domains"))
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

I find that the dispatch causes the warning, but why? My domains page have nothing much currently:

```
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import DomainsIndex from "./DomainsIndex.jsx"

export default connect()(DomainsIndex)
```

DomainsIndex

```
export default class DomainsIndex extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Domains</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

My `App.jsx`. `<Notifications />` is what displays the notifications

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Layout>
        <Panel>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/auth" />
            <Route component={TopBar} />
          </Switch>

          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
            <Route path="/auth/login" component={LoginBotBot} />
            <AuthenticatedRoute exact path="/domains" component={DomainsPage} />
            <AuthenticatedRoute exact path="/domain/:id" component={DomainPage} />
            <Route component={Http404} />
          </Switch>
          <Notifications />
        </Panel>
      </Layout>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
```

Comment: Can you upload the code to a repo for us to play around with it? It is kind of hard to figure out with this setup.

Comment: As a side note, rather than using .get().get() you should use .getIn([]).

Comment: In my experience this is not about the structure of the actions but more about the place from which the actions are triggered. Typically you see this error when triggering an action from `componentWillMount` or from `render`. Even by mistake, e.g. when writing `onClick={action()}` instead of `onClick={action}`.

Comment: Can you go line-by-line in the action creator `doLogin` to see which one is complaining, could it be the `addNotification` or the `push` method, right now there is not that much information to fully understand what is going on.

Comment: @cabolanoz its the push. Without that, I dont get the warning.

Comment: How does your `DomainsPage` look like?

Comment: Can you expand the stack trace for the warning in the console and share it ?

Answer (score 6):

Your `dispatch(push('/domains'))` comes along other dispatches that set the state for a connected component (presumably one that cares about notifications) that gets remounted/unmounted after the `push` takes effect.

As a workaround and proof of concept, try defering the `dispatch(push('/domains'))` call with a nested zero-second `setTimeout`. This should execute the `push` after any of the other actions finish (i.e. hopefully a render):

```
setTimeout(() => dispatch(push('/domains')), 0)
```

If that works, then you might want to reconsider your component structure. I suppose `Notifications` is a component you want to mount once and keep it there for the lifetime of the application. Try to avoid remounting it by placing it higher in the component tree, and making it a `PureComponent` (here are the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent)). Also, if the complexity of your application increases, you should consider using a library to handle async functionality like [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga).

Even though this warning usually appears because of a misplaced action call (e.g. calling an action on render: `onClick={action()}` instead of passing as a lambda: `onClick={() => action()}`), if your components look like you've mentioned (just rendering a `div`), then that is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: I tried setTimeout with 0 delay and 1s delay, both still results in the same error. I will try to add more details to my question

Comment: I'd say give us a link to a repo. Otherwise this is kind of impossible to pin down

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue in the past, and managed to resolve it using [redux-batched-actions](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions).

It's very useful for use-cases like yours when you dispatch multiples actions at once and you're unsure of when the updates will get triggered, with this, there will be only one single dispatch for multiple actions. In your case it seems that the subsequent `addNotification` is fine, but the third one is too much, maybe because it interacts with the history api.

I would try to do something like (assuming your setTimeout will be replaced by an api call of course):

```
import { batchActions } from 'redux-batched-actions'

export function doLogin (username, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {

    dispatch(loginRequest())
    console.log("Simulated login with", username, password)

    setTimeout(() => {

      dispatch(batchActions([
        loginSuccess(`PLACEHOLDER_TOKEN${Date.now()}`),
        addNotification({
          children: "Successfully logged in",
          type: "accept",
          timeout: 2000,
          action: "Ok"
        }),
        push("/domains")
      ]))

    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

Note that you'll have to download the package and `enableBatching` your reducer in your store creation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is when are you calling the `doLogin`, if you are calling it from within a `constructor`. If this is the case try moving it to `componentWillMount` although you should be calling this method from a button or enter hit in the login form.

This have been documented in [constructor should not mutate](https://github.com/patw0929/react-intl-tel-input/issues/79) If this is not the root of the problem you mind commented each line in doLogin to know exactly which line giving the state problem, my guess would be either the `push` or the `addNotification`

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info to give a certain answer. But what is for sure is that this warning is raised when you tries to `setState` inside `render` method.

Most often it happens when you are calling your handler functions instead of passing them as props to child `Component`. Like it happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387351/reactjs-warning-setstate-cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transiti) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426904/es6-warning-setstate-cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transition).

So my advice is to double check which `Components` are being rendered on your `/domains` route and how you are passing `onChange`, `onClick`, etc. handlers to them and to their children.

Answer (score 0):

In a react component when you call `setState({...})`, it causes the component to re-render and call all the life cycle methods which are involved in re-rendering of the component and `render` method is one of them

When in `render` if you call `setState({...})` it will cause a re-render and render will be called again and again hence this will trigger an infinite loop inside the javascript eventually leading to crashing of the app

Hence, not only in `render` but in any life-cycle method which is a part of re-render process `setState({...})` method shouldn't be called.

In your case the code might be triggering an update in the redux state while the code is still rendering and hence this causes re-render and react shows error