# Cannot update during an existing state transition error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Inside my render return() I have these:

```
<button onClick={ this.selectTimeframe('Today') }
        className={ this.setActiveIf('Today') } type="button">Today</button>
```

Which is this function:

```
selectTimeframe(timeframe) {
    // this.setState({ timeframe });
}
```

^ I have to comment out the setState for now otherwise I'll get that error I posted above and the app breaks.

I have this in my constructor:

`this.selectTimeframe = this.selectTimeframe.bind(this);`

I found this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387351/reactjs-warning-setstate-cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transiti), but it does not make sense, how am I suppose to pass in variable? Or is he saying that every unique button needs a unique function? As to avoid calling it inside of the render?

## Full code

```
import React from 'react';

export class TimeframeFilter extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            timeframe: 'Today'
        };

        this.selectTimeframe = this.selectTimeframe.bind(this);
        this.setActiveIf = this.setActiveIf.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('%c TimeframeFilter componentDidMount', 'background: #393939; color: #bada55', this.state);
    }

    selectTimeframe(timeframe) {
        // this.setState({ timeframe });
    }

    setActiveIf(timeframe) {
        return this.state.timeframe === timeframe ? 'btn btn-default active' : 'btn btn-default';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="fl">
                <span className="label label-default mr10">Timeframe</span>
                <div className="btn-group btn-group-sm mr20" role="group">
                    <button onClick={ this.selectTimeframe('Today') }
                            className={ this.setActiveIf('Today') } type="button">Today</button>
                    <button onClick={ this.selectTimeframe('Week') }
                            className={ this.setActiveIf('Week') } type="button">Week</button>
                    <button onClick={ this.selectTimeframe('Month') }
                            className={ this.setActiveIf('Month') } type="button">Month</button>
                    <button onClick={ this.selectTimeframe('Year') }
                            className={ this.setActiveIf('Year') } type="button">Year</button>
                    <button onClick={ this.selectTimeframe('All') }
                            className={ this.setActiveIf('All') } type="button">All</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TimeframeFilter;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be passing the value to the `onClick` function using `arrow function or bind method` otherwise it just executes to return value to `onClick`  everytime rerender occurs and if you use `setState` in it, it will call a `rerender` and the funciton to call again and thus repeating the process.

Do it like

```
<button onClick={ ()=> this.selectTimeframe('Today') }
        className={ this.setActiveIf('Today') } type="button">Today</button>
```

or

```
<button onClick={ this.selectTimeframe.bind(this, 'Today') }
        className={ this.setActiveIf('Today') } type="button">Today</button>
```

Hope I was able to explain it to you clearly. :)

**EDIT:** Although the above approach solves the problem but isn't the optimal approach due to the performance reasons. We should avoid method binding inside render because during re-rendering it will create the new methods instead of using the old one, that will affect the performance.

See this answer on **[How to avoid binding inside the render method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053622/how-to-avoid-binding-inside-render-method/45053753#45053753)**

Comment: Thank you, I get it now... I was calling the function every time. The `() =>` fixes that.

Comment: Glad, I was able to explain properly, :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently you call `this.selectTimeframe('Today')` in your render method.
You probably want to

`onClick={() => this.selectTimeframe('Today') }`

or a bit smarter way

```
<button onClick={ this.selectTimeframe.bind(this, 'Today') } className={ this.setActiveIf('Today') } type="button">Today</button>

selectTimeframe.bind(key) {
  switch(key){
    case 'Today':
      //your logic
      break;
  }
}
```