# React cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app with react-countdown-circle-timer installed. 
When the onComplete() method of the circle timer fires, I am setting the state but I get this warning:
`Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render').`

```
import React from 'react';
import { CountdownCircleTimer } from 'react-countdown-circle-timer';

export default class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            userMustWait: false
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CountdownCircleTimer
                isPlaying
                durationSeconds={3}
                colors={[["#004777", 0.33], ["#F7B801", 0.33], ["#A30000"]]}
                onComplete={() => { this.setState({ userMustWait: false }) }}
            />)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS: Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387351/reactjs-warning-setstate-cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transiti)

Comment: @keikai unfortunately not

Answer (score 1):

You have to write function instead doing in render itself

```
onclick(){
   this.setState({ userMustWait: false })    
}

render() {
        return (
            <CountdownCircleTimer
                isPlaying
                durationSeconds={3}
                colors={[["#004777", 0.33], ["#F7B801", 0.33], ["#A30000"]]}
                onComplete={() => this.onclick()}
            />)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that only the {

```
onclick(){
   this.setState({ userMustWait: false });
}

render() {
        return (
            <CountdownCircleTimer
                isPlaying
                durationSeconds={3}
                colors={[["#004777", 0.33], ["#F7B801", 0.33], ["#A30000"]]}
                onComplete={() => { this.onclick() }} // <-- on here
            />)
    }
```