# React Router warning Render methods should be a pure function of props and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In a `React` project Im using `react-router-dom version 5.2.0`. I want to navigate trough pages and components programmatically by calling `history.push(path)`. It seems navigation works but I get a warning:

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state
```

As I understand, the push functionality is setting state in render phase, but I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Difficult to help without seeing the relevant code. Also take a look at [ReactJS: Warning: setState(…): Cannot update during an existing state transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387351/reactjs-warning-setstate-cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transiti)

Comment: You may want to post the component code. You can use componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate depending on your needs if it's a class base component. useEffect if not. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect