# react error - Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  if(props.filterCriteria.timeRange){
    const start = props.filterCriteria.timeRange.start
    const end = props.filterCriteria.timeRange.end
    form.setFieldsValue({
      created: [moment(start, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'), moment(end, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')]
    })
  }
```

Add this to the function component and report an error：
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387351/reactjs-warning-setstate-cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transiti

Answer (score 2):

Call the setFieldsValue from within useEffect.